# Echarts decal in the tooltip

Tags: echarts

I am using Echart v5 to display two bar graph ( Multiple series) as you can see in the picture  the first bar graph I use a white background and a decal but I cannot use the decal in the legend and the tooltip icon of the series

how can i add decal to the icon in the legend and tooltip

[image: example picture]